# Incomplete LU decomposition of sparse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, matrix-factorization

I have a sparse matrix stored in CSR format. For this matrix, I would like to get the incomplete LU decomposition. I tried to find algorithms which can utilize the CSR format but I could not find anything. All work, papers, software seem to access the matrix by giving row index and column index like for COO format (`A[i,j]`).

Yes, this can be done, but I think that doing it this way costs a lot of time for looking for the correct matrix entry in CSR format as one has to iterate through a complete row to find the correct column.
Any ideas or papers or git repositories which I haven't found?

If there is no other possibility, what would be the fastest way to access elements in a CSR matrix? Simply iterate through the given row until the defined column is reached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of implementation, you definitely should take a look at Intel MKL's one.
Say, [`dcsrilu0`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-dcsrilu0) and [`dcsrilut`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-dcsrilut) (with threshold) accept the matrix in a [DSS format](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-dss-nonsymmetric-matrix-storage#042CD407-36A0-4AE9-AC9E-34E8E0A004D3) (I linked to a nonsymmetric one), which is a wrapper on top of a [three-array CSR storage](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-sparse-blas-csr-matrix-storage-format). (both pages would contain the same matrix as an example).

So, implementation-wise, you should be able to get the ILU from CSR without you reordering yourself.

It also certainly is worth taking a look at [SuperLU](https://github.com/xiaoyeli/superlu). However, it works with CCS, natively. Excerpt from the documentation:

> The factorization and solve routines in SuperLU are designed to handle column-wise storage only. If the input matrix $A$ is in row-oriented storage, i.e., in `SLU_NR` format, then the driver routines (`dgssv()` and `dgssvx()`) actually perform the LU decomposition on $A^T$, which is column-wise, and solve the system using the $L^T$ and $U^T$ factors. The data structures holding $L$ and $U$ on output are different (swapped) from the data structures you get from column-wise input.
>
> ...
>
> Alternatively, the users may call a utility routine `dCompRow_to_CompCol()` to convert the input matrix in `SLU_NR` format to another matrix in `SLU_NC` format, before calling SuperLU.

While the excerpt talks about the full factorize and solve, the same should be true for the incomplete "preconditioner"-related counterparts.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to look at Intel MKL. I missed the most obvious source. Just for information: Intel MKL has a reference to the book of Saad which actually has a Fortran routine.